# Active Directory Domain Login from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, active-directory

How do you go one step past merely validating credentials in Active Directory and actually log the user in?  so that the last login time changes in the command 'net user username /domain'...  I thought the ContextOptions.Negotiate in the ValidateCredentials method would achieve this, but it isn't.  What am I doing wrong?  Here is my Authenticate method.

```
public static bool Authenticate(ServiceInfo adConfig, string username, string password) {
using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, adConfig.Domain, adConfig.Container, adConfig.Username, adConfig.Password)) {
    if (principalContext.ValidateCredentials(username, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate)) {
        using (var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username)) {
            if (userPrincipal != null) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: there is a way to do this but I currently do it using all users you would have to change the code if I post the example below to fit your specific needs let me know if you would like to see how I am currently doing this

Comment: @MethodMan please. i would very much like to see how you are doing it